# Configuration of scrlayer-scrpage Package

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage

As I am using KOMA it ist recommended to use the package scrlayer-scrpage instead of fancy.

Unfortunately I am encountering some problems:
I am using scrbook, and the head and footer shoul look like:

- Head separation line
- on the left page - header: section
- on the right page - header: chapter, BUT without "chapter" at the beginning (only the number)
- on every page - footer: pagenumber

That's my code I am actually using:

```
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}
```

In combination with:

```
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\ifoot{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
```

But there are some bugs now I can't figure out myself:

- the pagenumber is missing on the new page of a chapter (with and without number)
- the chapter displayed in the header is not without "chapter" at the beginning
- After the TOC I have created a nomenclature with acronym. Unfortunately the header still is named Table of contents. How do I tell latex to change that the chapter has changed?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Remove the line `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}` from your code. Then the page style on chapter pages will be `plain`. To get no header entries on `plain` pages remove the optional argument of `\ohead`.

I guess that option `chapterprefix` is used in your document. To remove "chapter" from the header redefine `\chaptermarkformat`

```
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
```

[image]

[image]

Regarding your third question: Maybe you have to use `\addchap{Acronyms}`. If that does not help please ask a separat question with a MWE (minimal working example) that shows the issue.